# How may one convert from Lo.22/18 Prelim. to Schwarzeck / Lo22/17: EPSG29377?

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, transform

I am currently georeferencing an archival map with a set of coordinates from a Documents. Some of the coordinates are given in Schwarzeck / Lo22/17, the other points however are given in Lo22/18, a CRS that doesn't quite exist in QGIS. Upon further research, I found a quote from [this source](https://www.africangeomatics.com/namibian-map-system) which states:

“Prior to the official introduction of referenced projections in the 1950's and 1960's, the longitude of origin was either 15 or 18 E. On most cadastral documents these are general referred to as preliminary system and are annotated as Lo.22/15 Prelim or Lo.22/18 Prelim.“

I believe I have come across one of these documents which refer to Lo.22/18 Prelim Points. How may I convert from these points to the current Schwarzeck / Lo22/17 system being used? Mapping area is Namibia.

Here are some example coordinates(X,Y):

Point A: (-167194.72,102189.57)
Point B: (-166817.69,95118.18)
Point C: (-164407.95,89688.72)
Point D: (-163038.13,90183.06)
Point E: (-160153.81,94932.73)

Here is the document from which these coordinates are referenced:

[image]

(It is a German Document hence the Comma represents what would be a Decimal.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QGIS create the custom projection Schwarzeck/Lo22/18, based on Schwarzeck/Lo22/17:

```
+proj=tmerc +axis=wsu +lat_0=-22 +lon_0=18 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bess_nam +towgs84=616,97,-251,0,0,0,0 +to_meter=1.0000135965 +no_defs
```

Import the coordinates using custom Schwarzeck/Lo22/18,
then export to Schwarzeck/Lo22/17

Comment: Thank you so much, Hans! Worked like a charm. You are a genius.